# Google Sheets function runs but does not affect sheet content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Sheets script to perform the following:

- iterate through a specified sheet, finding rows that **do not** contain a specified value within a specified column
- store these rows as a range in a variable
- remove all other rows
- replace the sheet content with the stored rows

The script runs without error, but does not affect sheet content. I'm not sure what the issue is - any feedback is appreciated.

Here's the script:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Clear OI')
      .addItem('Clear OI', 'removeZeroOI')
      .addToUi();
}

function removeZeroOI() {

  // Deleting Rows Based on Cell Values
 
  //GLOBALS
  
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
  var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("mySheetName");
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  
  
  var DELETE_VAL = 0;
  var COL_TO_SEARCH = 13; //column N
  
  function main() {
    
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    
    var deleteSelectedRows = removeFilterSetVals();
    
    var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime)/1000;
    Logger.log("Runtime is: "+runTime + " seconds");
  };
  
  function removeFilterSetVals(){
    var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
    
    var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val){
      
      return val[COL_TO_SEARCH] != DELETE_VAL ;
    });
    
    RANGE.clearContent();
    
    var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,filteredRange.length, filteredRange[0].length);
    newRange.setValues(filteredRange);
  };
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are actually using your showing script, I think that in your script, when the function of `removeZeroOI()` is run, `main()` and `removeFilterSetVals()` are not run. By this, the script doesn't work while no error occurs.

When you want to run `main()` and `removeFilterSetVals()`, how about the following modifications?

#### Modified script:

```js
function removeZeroOI() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
  var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("mySheetName");
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var DELETE_VAL = 0;
  var COL_TO_SEARCH = 13; //column N

  main(); // Added

  function main() {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var deleteSelectedRows = removeFilterSetVals();
    var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
    Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
  };

  function removeFilterSetVals() {
    var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
    var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val) {
      return val[COL_TO_SEARCH] != DELETE_VAL;
    });
    RANGE.clearContent();
    var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1, 1, filteredRange.length, filteredRange[0]
      .length);
    newRange.setValues(filteredRange);
  };
}
```

And,

```js
function removeZeroOI() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
  var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("mySheetName");
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var DELETE_VAL = 0;
  var COL_TO_SEARCH = 13; //column N

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();

  // Script of "removeFilterSetVals()" is put here.
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val) {
    return val[COL_TO_SEARCH] != DELETE_VAL;
  });
  RANGE.clearContent();
  var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1, 1, filteredRange.length, filteredRange[0]
    .length);
  newRange.setValues(filteredRange);

  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: I ran the second mod that you provided and it functioned perfectly. Thank you